# Set image Id to image added using drag and drop

Tags: android, image, gridview, drag-and-drop, getter-setter

I need to know which image is in which cell, so I have only tried using `.setId()` and `.getId()`. But if there's any other way to do this, just let me know.

Images are added when I click a button. I have nothing showing where they appear, but here's my problem, I'm trying to add a Id to each image that I'm able to add. So when I drop them in the GridView and click one of them I can do something else if the `Id` is the correct one, like, `if (Id == 1) open... else if (id == 2) open other thing`. But I can't get the `Id` to be saved to the image (or saved to that `ImageCell`).

Example of the problem I'm getting: If I added image1 which have Id1 and then add image2 which have Id2 the image1 Id will change to the last image added (in this case image2 Id). I have tried a lot of different ways of setting the Id, but I'm still getting the last image id in the first one dropped.

I'm using a Toast to show the image dropped Id. This is the ImageCell code.

```
public void onDrop(DragSource source, int x, int y, int xOffset, int yOffset,
    DragView dragView, Object dragInfo)
{
mEmpty = false;

ImageView sourceView = (ImageView) source;
sourceView.setId(DragActivity.m);
Drawable d = sourceView.getDrawable ();
this.setId(sourceView.getId());
if (d != null) {
   this.setImageDrawable (d);
   this.setId(sourceView.getId());
   prueba = this.getId();
}
toast ("" + prueba);
}
```

DragActivity.m is just a variable that's used to change the picture.

```
public void addNewImageToScreen() {
    int resourceId = R.drawable.hello;

    m = mImageCount % 3;
    if (m == 1) {
        resourceId = R.drawable.photo1;
    } else if (m == 2) {
        resourceId = R.drawable.photo2;
    }
    addNewImageToScreen(resourceId);
}
```

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: Common is not posible that no one have any idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are trying to swap images in that case you can identify `ImageView` uniquely by tag like this:

```
ImageView imageView = new ImageView(_context);
imageView.setTag(1);
```

And then on `GridView`'s / `ImageView`'s click check its tag like this:

```
gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
            long arg3) {

        Tag = (Integer) arg1.getTag();

    }
}
```

Comment: I see what you mean, but I want to check if they are connected.  Something like: If imageCell0 have hello and imageCell1 have hello then change both images.

Comment: in that case check tags and compare them

Comment: Perfect!! Just what I needed, after days of thinking and understanding what tag is I make it work. Thanks!!